# iperf tests with Android Q

Tags: android, storage, permission-denied, android-10.0, iperf

I am attempting to upgrade an existing iperf application to Android Q. I am running into trouble when executing the command line - error=13, Permission denied to be specific. Is this due to the new file access restrictions on Q? I have tried *android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"* with no avail. I am beginning to think that this application is no longer possible with the new storage access requirements.

**Command:**
[/data/user/0/MYPACKAGENAME/iperf, -c, IPADDRESS, -p, 16000, -l, 1K, -t, 10, -i, 0, -b, 50M, -u, -R, -J]

**Error:**
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/user/0/MYPACKAGENAME/iperf": error=13, Permission denied

Comment: Did you get solution for Android Q?

Comment: I have not - it looks like you can no longer run exce commands - trying to find a work around still

Comment: If you find solution, please ping here